# Does PHP support Composite Data Type?

Tags: php

Does PHP supports Composite data type? If yes, then how could I create it?

Comment: You mean the objects?. In PHP object structure to store complex information in your problem domain.

Comment: yes you can, through the use of objects (if composite data type is considered as the mix of several primitives).. but have you tried to search the answer for this in the internet before posting the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that by composite data types you mean objects, then yes PHP does support them. In order to create objects you have to create classes.
For example:

```
class SimpleClass
    {
      // property declaration
       public $var = 'a default value';
       // method declaration
       public function displayVar() {
          echo $this->var;
       }
    }
```

Then you can instantiate an object of this class as follows:
`$obj  = new SimpleClass()`.
For more information:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php